# Tooltip(help message)in orbeon: conditional help message display in orbeon

Tags: orbeon

I have an issue regarding displaying help message in orbeon form.
The help message is always displayed.I didn't find a way to add condition for displaying this help message.

Comment: Are you saying that you'd like the help to only be shown upon some condition being met, or the message itself to be different depending on some condition?

Comment: Is this an outstanding issue for you? If it is, have you seen my previous message?